# Is there a way to highlight just certain parts of text in an RStudio text string?

Tags: r, regex, pdf, highlight, kableextra

Is there a way where I can tell R that I want all words within the angular brackets to be highlighted. It can be highlighted, a different font color, bold, italicize, I just want it to stand out.

I'm using kableExtra to create a good-looking tables but it isn't necessary.

Thank you.

```
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3),"String"=c("This is <my> string.","This is <another> string.","This is <a> third string."))

#Use KableExtra to create a nice-looking pdf table.
kable(df, "latex", booktabs = T,linesep = "",
      col.names = c("ID",
                    "String")) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F)
```